# Cannot resolve method getContext() in android.support.v4.app.Fragment (version 21.0.3) Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I've come accoss a problem that I can't seem seem to understand why it's happening  . I've got a few Fragments in my project using the support v4 library (version 21.0.3) . In these fragments I used the getContext() method for example to show Toasts .
But yesterday suddently all getContext in my project broke and Android Studio shows me 26 errors while compiling . Here's one of the multiple exemples that broke

```
    package com.example.project.ui.fragment;


    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import com.example.project.R;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class ListSizesFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<String> sizes;

    private ListView listViewSizes;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


    public ListSizesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_sizes, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        listViewSizes = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewBlogs);
        sizes = new ArrayList<>(MAX_SIZES);
        sizes.addAll(getValueSizes())

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sizes);
        listViewSizes.setAdapter(adapter);
        listViewSizes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String resultSize = adapter.getItem(position);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"result :"+resultSize,Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();               getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

From what I can see in the Android documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getContext()) getContext is a method of the support-v4 Fragment so I'm stuck at trying to figure out what's the problem .

In that project I also had a ViewPager and I can't have the same problem with the addOnPageListener method .

I've tried Rebuilding the Project and Resyncing the project with the Gradle file but to no avail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Fragment#getContext()` was added in version 23 of the support library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/support_api_diff/23/changes/android.support.v4.app.Fragment.html). If you inadvertently flipped your build.gradle files to use an older version (you say 21.0.3), then `getContext()` is not supported.

Comment: So I'm looking in the local history and in the build.gradle dependencies compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+' was changed to compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3' yesterday when that problem occured . However trying to use the latest version back got me another error : _Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'._

Comment: If I inadvertently flipped my build.gradle files, how do I "unflip" them?  What file should I edit in order to change the support library version?

Comment: @calvillo Your module's build.gradle and specifically the `compile "com.android.support...` there

Comment: @laalto that line doesn't exist.  I have 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0' and 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'.  Any ideas?

Comment: @calvillo: Yes you'll get 22.2.0 support libs that way. Update the version numbers.

Comment: try: compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.1.1'