# Error for getContext() after updating Android studio

Tags: android

I have recently updated Android Studio and SDK. After that when I am opening old projects getting error could not find getContext(). Anybody have same issue?

Comment: I am using build tools version 22.0.1 and target sdk is 23.

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34240770/cannot-resolve-method-getcontext-in-android-support-v4-app-fragment-version-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey I have faced the same issue and I resolved it as follows:-

1. It is happening because you have updated your sdk with latest build tools version.
2. If your targeted and compiled version is 22 then just change it to 23.
3. Use latest build tools version for 23 ie. 23.0.2
4. Also change your support libraries to 23.

These change fixed my issue with getContext(). Let me know if it works for you.